# KVM installation: Unable to locate package ia32-libs-multiarch

Tags: android-studio, 64-bit, ubuntu-14.04, kvm

I'm trying to install KVM for avd of android studio and I ran this command:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils ia32-libs-multiarch
```

But on running it gives me this error:

```
Unable to locate package ia32-libs-multiarch
```

I tried resolving it using this command but that also didn't work:

```
sudo apt-get install librtmp0 librtmp0:i386
```

I'm running a 64-bit machine with ubuntu 14.04

Is what I'm doing the required steps for 32-bit???

Answer (score 38):

I've gotten the same error `Unable to locate package ia32-libs-multiarch`

Then I decided to trust Ubuntu KVM Installation help page and tried it out.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation

Actually there is only one difference. The command doesn't include `ia32-libs-multiarch` part.

Outcome is successful.

```
$ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

Answer (score 20):

I believe you are trying to run AVD on Linux machine in KVM mode(called HAXM on Windows and OS X machines)

Install KVM by executing following command

```
$ sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin virtinst bridge-utils cpu-checker
```

Next check KVM installed successfully by executing following command

```
$ kvm-ok
```

the output will be something like this

```
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

Next add your username to **KVM** and **libvirtd** and run the AVD from the tools directory of your android SDK

```
$sudo adduser `id -un` libvirtd
$sudo adduser `id -un` kvm

$ ./emulator64-x86 -avd < your AVD name> -qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm
```

**Note:** To find the names of your available AVDs, open the AVD manager from tools folder of android sdk by executing command `$./android avd`

Find more information on installing KVM form these links,
[Link 1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation)
[Link 2](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-kvm-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-server/)

Comment: adduser: The group `libvirtd' does not exist. https://askubuntu.com/a/963051/996832 solved my issue.

Answer (score 18):

### Install Necessary Packages to avoid this error - Updated for 2020

Cosmic (18.10) or later

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils
```

Lucid (10.04) or later

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
```

based on ubuntu help community [site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation)

Comment: if it didn't work, make sure your username is added to the group libvirtd after the installation. see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation) for the guide